# How to define @OneToMany in parent entity when child has composite PK?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, composite-key, referential-integrity

My `Parent` class has two child classes:  `Child` and `ParentHobby`.  The Child class has a singular PK and the `@OneToMany` mapping on it works.  The problem is that I don't know how to map it on the ParentHobby class, which has a composite PK.

**Parent:**

```
//this works
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Child> childList;

//this DOES NOT work
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<ParentHobby> hobbyList;
```

**Child:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD")
public class Child {


    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="CHILD_SEQ", sequenceName="CHILD_DB_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="CHILD_SEQ")
    @Column(name="CHILD_ID")
    private long childID;

    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    private Parent parent;
```

**ParentHobby:**

@Entity
@Table(name="PARENT_HOBBY")
public class ParentHobby {

```
@EmbeddedId
private ParentHobbyPK id;
```

**ParentHobbyPK:**

```
@Embeddable
public class ParentHobbyPK {

    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    private Parent parent;

    @Column(name="HOBBY_ID")
    private String hobbyID;
```

The exception I get at compile time is:

```
mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: ParentHobby.parent in Parent.hobbyList
```

**How can I define a @OneToMany relationship in a parent entity when the child has a composite primary key?**

<sub>SIMILAR:</sub>

[@OneToMany relationship with Composite key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162755/onetomany-relationship-with-composite-key)

[Hibernate Entity mapping when Foreign key is part of the composite primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669034/hibernate-entity-mapping-when-foreign-key-is-part-of-the-composite-primary-key)

[JPA composite key @OneToMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569702/jpa-composite-key-onetomany)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a derived identity.

`ParentHobbyPK` should look like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class ParentHobbyPK {
    @Column(name="HOBBY_ID")
    private String hobbyID;
    private long parentID; // corresponds to the PK type of Parent
}
```

`ParentHobby` should look like this (the important thing being the `@MapsId` annotation):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PARENT_HOBBY")
public class ParentHobby {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ParentHobbyPK id;

    @MapsId("parentID") // maps parentID attribute of the embedded ID
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private Parent parent;

    ...
}
```

Derived identity is discussed in JPA 2.1 spec, section 2.4.1.

Comment: Finally found an answer that made it clear to me! I was always making the same mistake -- you have to look out what are you putting into @MapsId as an argument, I was always putting there name of id property of Parent class, not of the composite key!